# git: how do I work with a submodule when two people are updating it (two remotes)?

Tags: git, synchronization, git-submodules

I have a project that relies on a git submodule.  The submodule is also a repository I own, but cloned from another github repository of another user.

```
The layout is:
      my_project/
         my_submodule/
```

I would like to keep my submodule main branch clean and (optionally) synced to the other user's github repository (its main branch also), so I don't mess it up.
But I would like to create new branches and new commits in those new branches of my own submodule so I can send PRs to github and have an "all_commits" branch that holds all my changes to the submodule so I can check the changes with the latest version of my_project.  Basically I am looking to this workflow:

```
$ cd my_submodule/
$ git switch main
$ git branch new_pr
$ git checkout new_pr
$ emacs somefile.cpp  # change some file
$ git commit -a
$ git push -u origin new_pr
$ git switch all_commits
$ git merge new_pr     # so all_commits holds all my prs and changes
```

Once the pr is accepted:

```
$ cd my_submodule
$ git switch main
$ git "sync" to orig_main  # this is the command I am missing
$ git push -u origin main  # store the new_pr change in my own repository
$ git branch -D new_pr     # remove the new_pr now that it was accepted
```

Answer (score 0):

One step missing is to refresh the main branch with the original repository ("the other user's github repository")

```
$ cd my_submodule/
$ git switch main

$ # if not already done
$ git remote add upstream https://url/other/user/repo

$ git fetch upstream
$ # reset main to the other user's repo main branch
$ git switch -C main upstream/main
$ # create a new PR based on the latest from upstream/main:
$ git switch -c new_pr
```